# I2C interfacing between Raspberry Pi Pico and LCD-Display 1602A doesn't work

Tags: arduino, i2c, lcd, raspberry-pi-pico

I want do display text on my LCD 1602A display using a Raspberry Pi Pico and PlatformIO with Arduino library. Since the address pads on the PCF8574 board are empty, my address should be 0x3F or 0x27. Both addresses are not working. The status LED on the Board is working fine.
As recommended, I performed an I2C Scan using MicroPython and it returned the address 0x27 as device address. However I still can't display data on the display.

Code:

```cpp
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h>

// I2C TWs
#define SDA                     0 // GPIO 0 (I2C0 SDA)
#define SCL                     1 // GPIO 1 (I2C0 SCL)

// LCD-Display data
#define LCD_DEVICE_ADDRESS      0x27
#define LCD_DEVICE_COLUMNS      16
#define LCD_DEVICE_ROWS         2

// New LCD instance + init I2C
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(LCD_DEVICE_ADDRESS, LCD_DEVICE_COLUMNS, LCD_DEVICE_ROWS);
arduino::MbedI2C use_wire(SDA, SCL);

void setup()
{
    // set Board LED to output
    pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT); 

    // I2C start
    use_wire.begin();

    // init LCD
    lcd.init();

    // activate Backlight of display
    lcd.backlight();
}

void loop()
{
    // Set Builtin LED to high
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

    // Display output
    lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
    lcd.print("Hello World");
}
```

Comment: Have you done anything to prove you've set up the I2C bus in the Pi? Does your /boot/config.txt include the line turning on I2C? What do you get when you attempt to read from all I2C addresses (using the command <i2cdetect -y 1> from memory)? Is there anything else on the I2C bus you can talk to?

Comment: I am not using a Raspberry Pi, I am using a Pi Pico.

Comment: Which "LCD 1602A" and "PCF8574 board" you mean? How did you connect those together? What supply voltages are used?

Comment: They are connected together as a prebuild module. For supply voltage i use to VCC pin on the pico. SDA and SCL are connected to GPIO26 and 27 (seen in the Code) and GND to GND.

Comment: Well, even if you know it, we don't know what module that is and how it is supposed to be connected, and to what supply voltage. We don't also know what voltage VCC is, and we don't know if the LCD module or the Pico module has pull-up resistors or did you apply them. If VCC is 3.3 does the display require 5V? We also don't know if you connected to correct module pins 31 and 32 which are GPIO26 and GPIO27.

Comment: The display works fine with 3.3 V. I also changed to GPIO20 and 21 since I2C0 is located there. The display lights up when i connect it to VCC, however I can't display any data on the display

Comment: I remember (if not wrong) that I used a "command" to see all I2C wired on Raspberry pi. Did you use it? https://learn.adafruit.com/scanning-i2c-addresses/raspberry-pi

Comment: That's for the Raspberry Pi, but I want to display on a LCD Display with I2C Module using Raspberry Pi Pico. The display itself works, but I don't get any output and I don't get whats wrong with the code.

Comment: Do I maybe have to change Pin values because of the arduino framework?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GPIO pins 26 and 27 on the Pi Pico are for I2C1, not I2C0. That is likely your problem, since in your code comment you note them as I2C0. Additionally some projects using this display module have noted you may need to use I2C Address 0x26 or 0x3F, so try running your code with those. [This hackster project](https://www.hackster.io/mr-alam/how-to-use-i2c-pins-in-raspberry-pi-pico-i2c-scanner-code-8f489f) explains how to see if there are any I2C devices on the Pi Pico bus, so until you can see the display module at all assume you are setting up the I2C connection incorrectly.

Comment: I updated the question and performed a scan as explained in the link you sent me. It returns as address 0x27, I still can't display text on the Display however. I also used I2C0 on GPIO0 and 1 (as seen in the code).

Comment: Seeing it is a good step. I would try copying a script from a project like the hackster one I linked and starting from there - I notice a lot of them use lcd.begin() and lcd.write() so maybe see if incorporating those makes a difference?